# Finding relevant combinations of predictors

Tags: predictive-models, predictor, forecast-combination

I am currently working on a data set consisting of 300 predictors and a dependent variable. The predictors are categorical variables (taking values 0,1) and for every observation only a subset of them is active, i.e. taking the value 1.

Every predictor is a client and the predictor takes the value one, if a client has bought a product on a given day. Typically the clients just buy the product now and then without any implications, but if certain clients buy the product together in a relatively short time, that typically signals an increase in the demand for that product. I am trying to identify the clients that (when acting together) predict this increase in demand.

As a consequence, every single predictor is unrelated with the outcome of the dependent variable, but if specific combinations of the predictors are active at the same time, we should see some predictive power.

In more technical terms, for every predictor $X_i$, the regression $Y \sim X_i$ will not be significant. However, for a (cleverly selected) subset of predictors $(i,j,k,l)$, the regression $Y\sim AUX$ for an auxiliary variable $AUX= X_i  X_j  X_k  X_l$  would be significant.

$AUX = 1$ is equivalent $X_i = X_j = X_k = X_l = 1$. So the regression $Y\sim AUX$ being significant  simply means, that specific combinations of predictors, that are "on" at the same time, have predictive power.

Four variables is only an example, I would expect to have to consider all subsets up to size 20. And the dimensionality of the problem is the reason I am writing here. I am in need of some smarter methods, as just trying out all the different predictor combinations is not possible.

Are there any standard methods to handle these situations? Potentially methods beyond regression methods?

Comment: If you're sure that "every single predictor is unrelated with the outcome of the dependent variable," then aren't you done?  Drop all the predictors because you know they're useless.  Including them could only deceive you into overfitting the model.

Comment: @whuber, what I mean is the following. For every i, the regression Y ~ X_i will not be significant. However, for a subset of predictors (i,j,k,l), if I construct an auxilliary variable AUX= X_i  * X_j * X_k * X_l and I did a regression Y~AUX, the result would be significant.

My question is, if there is any theory how to select subsets of predictors that are relevant for the regression. With 300+ predictors it does not seem feasible to try out all possible combinations of predictors that can be constructed from 300+ predictors.

Comment: That is an unusual definition of "relevant": I doubt it has ever appeared before.  For general approaches to selecting variables, though, look at the posts here on [model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=model+selection).

Comment: @whuber, thank you for your help. When you say "I doubt it has ever appeared before", do you mean there is not much literature available. I am not from the field (statistics), so I am not very knowledgeable about the existing literature. Generally the problem does not seem overly complicated, it the end it is just about finding subsets of predictors that have predictive power when every predictor in the subset is active and discarding those subsets that do not have any relevance. But potentially I am a bit naive here. Thanks again.

Comment: Your criterion for relevance is unusual but interesting. You refer to exactly four variables. Is that what you intend, or do you mean to explore all possible subsets of any size? Incidentally, this product is often called a "(four-way) interaction." It is rare for people to explore interactions more complex than three-way: they become too numerous and difficult to interpret. Note that because there are $300$ variables, there are $\binom{300}{4}$ (around 330 million) four-way interactions and $2^{300}$ (about 2e+90) subsets. Either suggests you're looking at too many possibilities.

Comment: @whuber, that is correct. Four variables is only an example. Would expect to have to consider all subsets up to size 20. And the dimensionality of the problem is pretty much the reason I am writing here. I am in need of some smarter methods, as just trying out all the different predictor combinations is not possible. Potentially, I might have to consider other methods than regression. We shall see...

Comment: @whuber, and to just add some idea about the real world problem behind the question. Every predictor is a client and the predictor takes the value one, if a client has bought a product on a given day. Typically the clients just buy the product now and then without any implications, but if certain clients buy the product together in a relatively short time, that typically signals an increase in the demand for that product. I am trying to identify the clients that (when trading together) predict this increase in demand.

Comment: The application is intriguing; it might suggest some methods not otherwise indicated by your abstract description.  Please incorporate the information from your last two comments into the question itself.